# My modal into electron dont open when i click into the button

Tags: html, vue.js, electron

I expected that by clicking on the Editar button, within #app, the modal would open, but it does not open at all !. I dont know if my js logic are wrong or my html are wrong!

When i try to use some function for the Modal, they continue dont work.
What i need to do for solved this?

JavaScript code are in final

full HTML:
https://pastebin.com/9GGbQ7WS

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>directories</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/photon.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- HTML5Shiv -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!-- Estilo customizado 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">-->
        <!-- Electron Javascript -->

      </head>

      <body>
       <div class="window">
         <header class="toolbar toolbar-header">
          <h1 class="title"></h1>
           <div class="toolbar-actions">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="icon icon-home"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="icon icon-folder"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-default active">
            <span class="icon icon-cloud"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="icon icon-popup"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="icon icon-shuffle"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-default">
          <span class="icon icon-home icon-text"></span>
          Filters
        </button>

        <button class="btn btn-default btn-dropdown pull-right">
          <span class="icon icon-megaphone"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
         </header>
      <div class="window-content">
        <div class="pane-group">
          <div class="pane-sm sidebar">...</div>
          <div class="pane">
             <h2 class="col-md-12 text-center">
    Creates a table to show customer data whit these infos:</h2> 
            <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>nome</th>
              <th>cpf</th>
              <th>endereco</th>
              <th>telefone</th>
              <th>placa do carro</th>
              <th>compania</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>



          <tbody>
            <tr id="app">
              <td v-for = "cliente in clientes">
              {{cliente.nome}}
              </td>
              <td v-for = "cliente in clientes">
              {{cliente.cpf}}
              </td>
              <td v-for = "cliente in clientes">
              {{cliente.endereco}}
              </td>
              <td v-for = "cliente in clientes">
              {{cliente.telefone}}
              </td>
              <td v-for = "cliente in clientes">
              {{cliente.placa}}
              </td>
              <td v-for = "cliente in clientes">
              {{cliente.compania}}
              </td>

        *********HERE IS THE BUTTON. IDONT KNOW THE ERROR*************
              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-negative" @click="editClient" >Editar</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="toolbar toolbar-footer">

*****************The modal that does not open when clicking into the button**************

        <h1 class="title">Modal</h1>
      </footer>
    </div>

        <div id="modal-template" class="modal">
              <div class="wrap">
                 <form action="" class="col-md-12 pane-body" id="cadastro-cliente">
            <div class="container row  justify-content-center">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <h2 class="col-md-12 text-center">Cadastro do cliente</h2> 
              <div class="form-group col-md-12 justify-content-center">
                <label for="nome">Nome Completo</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="nome" v-model="client nome" placeholder="Nome Completo">
                  </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cpf" id="cpf" v-model="client cpf" placeholder="CPF com 9 digitos">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
             <label for="endereco">Endereço</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endereco" v-model="client endereco" id="endereco" placeholder="ex: Rua Professor araujo, 12345">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefone" id="telefone" v-model="client telefone" placeholder="ex: 539822232512">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="placa">Placa do carro</label>
              <input type="placa" class="form-control" name="placa" id="placa" v-model="client placa" placeholder="ex: asd-1234">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="compania">Compania</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="compania" id="compania" v-model="client compania" placeholder="ex: asd-1234">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="justify-content-center pb-5">
              <button type="button" id="salvar" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-negative" @click="showModal=false">Fechar</button>
              <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-negative" @click="showModal=false">Fechar</button>-->
            </div> 
            </div>
          </form>
              </div>
        </div>
      </body>


***************JAVASCRIPT CODE*************
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
        <script >
        var read = require('read-file-utf8')
        var loki = require('lokijs');
        var db = new loki('db.json');
        var data = read(__dirname+'/loki.json');
        db.loadJSON(data);
        window.vue = require('vue');
        var clientes = db.getCollection('clientes');
        console.log(db);

        //inicio inicialização modal
        Vue.component('modal', {
        template: '#modal-template'
        })// fim inicializção modal

        new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            clientes: [],
            showModal: false
          },
          mounted: function(){
            this.clientes = clientes.data;
            console.log(this.clientes);
          },
          methods:{
            editClient:function(){
              showModal: true
            }
          }
        })
        </script>
```

Comment: one of the attributes on your button is "@click", maybe if you remove the @-symbol it will work.

Comment: doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access showModal in the wrong scope. (You are missing `this`)

`this.showModal = true` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED BOYS! I created a modal with bootstrap, but it was missing the jquery then I used the command: npm install jquery --save,
to download the jquery and insert a call script inside the electron.

```
<script> window. $ = window.jQuery = require ('jquery'); </ script>
```

Right after that I used the:

```
 <script src = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity = "sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3 + MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW / JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin = "anonymous"> </ script>
```

to call the bootstrap library and it worked!